# How to get url values with window.location.hash and reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, search, window.location

I have this url http://localhost:3000/#/consultation/?idc=xxxd?iduser=Hyfzjg2 and I want to get the value of idc and iduser for using it on my APIs with ReactJs.

I try this:

```
let isInitialized = false;
const initialValues = {};
const initValues = () => {
    if (isInitialized === false) {
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash);
        const values = [
            { urlKey: "idc", stateKey: "idC" },
            { urlKey: "iduser", stateKey: "idUser" },
        ];
        values.forEach(item => {
            const urlValue = searchParams.get(item.urlKey)
            if (urlValue) {
                initialValues[item.stateKey] = urlValue;
            }
        });
        isInitialized = true;
    }
    return initialValues;
};

console.log(initValues())
```

When I run it, I get `{}` an empty value.

How can I get the value of `idc` and `iduser` ?

Comment: Your URL does not _have_ a `search` component resp. query string.

Comment: @CBroe I correct it, with `window.location.hash`

Comment: Not sure if the URLSearchParams constructor will parse such a value correctly. MDN says, a leading `?` gets ignored, but your value still starts with `#/consultation/`.

Comment: @CBroe thank you, you can check my answer, it works well

Answer (score 1):

I think you're path isn't constructed correctly:

If you have the path `http://localhost:3000/consultation` and you want to add a query string, that would be `http://localhost:3000/consultation?idc=xxxx` and
`window.location.search` would be `?idc=xxxx` then.

The # is a selector for an element on your page, for example #section=4, so you would typically scroll to that section. This would look like this:

`http://localhost:3000/consultation#section=4`
and `window.location.hash` would be "#section=4"

Comment: _“I think you're path isn't constructed correctly”_ - this kind of URL structure is pretty common for “one page” applications, or systems that use client-side routing. Changing the _actual_ query string would force a reload of the current page; only changing the URL fragment portion does not do that. So a “fake” query string placed _inside_ the fragment is used in those kind of scenarios.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, didn't know that.
Then your solution definitely makes sense, sorry @CodeLover!

Answer (score 0):

I correct it and It works well :

```
const  getUrlParams = (search) =>{
  let hashes = search.slice(search.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')
  return hashes.reduce((params, hash) => {
      let [key, val] = hash.split('=')
      return Object.assign(params, {[key]: decodeURIComponent(val)})
  }, {})
}

console.log(getUrlParams(window.location.hash))
```